# JQuery FullCalendar CSS error with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I'm working with JQuery FullCalendar library, and I have a function that paints certain lines of the calendar conditionally. My function Works fine in Internet explorer, but the line's color isn't changed when I use Google Chrome Browser. I've used 'style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF;"' instead '.css('background-color', '#FFFFFF;')', but nothing happens. What is the best way to set background color of a componente to show it correctly in Google Chrome browser? Below is my code. I'm using HTML entities for '&&', '>', '<', etc., because this function is embeded in a JSF XHTML file.

```
 if(timeSlot &gt;= str &amp;&amp; timeSlot &lt; obj.horaTermino)    //Change 13 and 18 according to what you need
{


  $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF;');
    //$(this).closest('tr').style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF;";


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the hex color value so you have:

```
$(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
```

Comment: Thank you. Your tip worked perfectly. What shame... this is a so simple thing! Haha!